# She went to work

Tags: tense

I dropped my wife at company.

Then I sent my son to nursery.

My son asked me, "Where is mummy."

> "She went to work."
>
> "She goes to work."

We just leave the company for 1 minutes.

Should we use present or past tense?

Comment: What kind of company you left? You left the company, where does your wife work? Or you left the company of young people with whom you drank alcoholic beverages?

Comment: She is at work now. 'present tense'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more typical English speaking answer to your son's question would use the present tense with the preposition "at"

> She's at work.

The past tense "She went to work" sounds a little awkward if you've left only a minute ago, and you are the one that dropped her off.  If your wife took herself to work, then "She went to work" would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

> She **went to** work.

is OK. It indicates that she left earlier, and is now at work.

> She **goes to** work.

indicates something she does in general, or on a regular basis.

> I miss my mommy. Where does she go everyday?
>
> She goes to work.